# Can't connect to database error

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

The site works perfectly  on camp but I keep getting  this error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in /storage/ssd1/760/4443760/public_html/conn.php:6
>   Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd1/760/4443760/public_html/index.php(2):
>   include() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /storage/ssd1/760/4443760/public_html/conn.php on line 6

Comment: Probably the system you see these error messages on is running PHP7+. mysql() has been removed from those versions of PHP. You shouldn't be using it for new code. Use mysqli() instead.

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_*** functions have been removed in PHP7

You probably have a php7 in XAMPP Please use PDO and... Feel the power of the light side:)

Link to nice wiki page about :)
This link try it

[PDO try it](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_*** functions have been removed in PHP7!

[PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)